# `bash_profile` doesn't load `export` command

Tags: linux, bash, adb

Mine might be an easy question but don't know how to solve yet...

```
(base) hsy@Deepin-hsy:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb
```

I can call `./adb` if I am already in the path,
and I have set the following `export` command in my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/home/hsy/Library/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Why I still can't use `adb` command in my terminal? appreciate any help.

Comment: You put `Sdk` in the first snippet but `sdk` in the second one. Is that a typo? If not, that might be the error

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for mentioning! I have made the change and rebooted, still no luck. What else can be the cause?

Comment: Just to be sure: you also mention your `bash_profile`, but the file should be `.bash_profile` (notice the dot at the start of the filename). Again, is that a typo? If not, then that's another possible error

Comment: @Miguel forgot to the leading dot here, but yes, I appended in both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` and double confirmed Im using bash...

Comment: After checking [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) my only idea is that you try to remove the `export` from the command

Comment: `./adb` already contains a path, it won't use your `PATH` variable :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, it can be called because I am within `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`, if I include `export PATH=/home/hsy/Library/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` without `$PATH` then `./adb` can be called anywhere. However I want to call `adb` not `./adb`

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for the reading, I was trying to bring executables from `/home/hsy/Library/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` to my path... is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: @Yang Where is your home directory (`echo ~`)? `~/Android/` doesn’t look like the same directory as `/home/hsy/Library/Android/`.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks a ton!!!!! it is `/home/hsy/Android`, seems Android Studio changed their install location. You save me hours!!!

Comment: Sorry then, it must be some specific feature by Android SDK. Since that isn't how Linux shells typically handle paths I thought it might be a typo.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `./adb` will run `adb` in the current directory.  `adb` will (try to) find it in `$PATH`. How is that not ‘_how Linux shells typically handle paths_’?!

Comment: @Biffen Read the OP's comment from an hour ago. He says that under certain arrangements *`./adb` can be called anywhere*. As you say, that's not how bash works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question for future seekers.

Android Studio installed the `adb` under `/home/$USER/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` on Deepin, while [Expo tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator/) gives the recommendation of `export PATH=/home/$USER/Library/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`.

1. There is no Library folder in the path
2. the `Sdk` has been capitalized

Good luck on your journey :)